# Makefile and directory structure

Tags: c++, make

I am looking for improvements for this basic makefile and directory structure. I know this is overkill and could be compiled with one line in a flat directory structure, but I want to use this as a learning exercise.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed -std=c++11 
LIBS=-lpthread
SRC=$(PWD)/src
BUILDDIR=$(PWD)/build
OUTDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/bin
TEMPDIR=$(BUILDDIR)/tmp
MKDIR_P = mkdir -p

.PHONY: directories clean run

all: directories $(OUTDIR)/terminal

$(OUTDIR)/terminal: $(TEMPDIR)/main.o $(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o $(TEMPDIR)/main.o $(LIBS) -o $(OUTDIR)/terminal

$(TEMPDIR)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/terminal.hpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)/main.cpp -o $(TEMPDIR)/main.o

$(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o: $(SRC)/terminal.cpp $(SRC)/terminal.hpp
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC)/terminal.cpp -o $(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o

directories: ${OUTDIR} $(TEMPDIR)

$(OUTDIR): 
    ${MKDIR_P} $(OUTDIR)

$(TEMPDIR):
    ${MKDIR_P} $(TEMPDIR)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)

run:
    $(OUTDIR)/terminal
```

Comment: GNU make, I assume?

Comment: Yes. <10 more characters for yes/no question.>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Stem rules:

  Spelling out compilation rule for each object file is tedious and error prone.

  ```
  $(TEMPDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
      $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
  ```

  takes care about all of them.
- Autodependencies:

  Spelling out dependencies for each object file is tedious and error prone. `gcc` can do it for you:

  ```
  $(TEMPDIR)/main.d: $(SRC)/main.c
      $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $< -o $@

  -include $(TEMPDIR)/main.d
  ```

  Of course you we don't want to spell it out for each source file, which naturally leads us to the next step.
- Use macros. Shall you add more source files, only `FILES` needs to be modified.

  ```
  FILES = main.c terminal.c
  SOURCES = $(patsubst %,$(SRC)/%,$(FILES))
  OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,$(TEMPDIR)/%.o,$(FILES))
  DEPS    = $(patsubst %.c.$(TEMPDIR)/%.d,$(FILES))

  $(TEMPDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
      $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

  $(TEMPDIR)/%.d: $(SRC)/%.c
      $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -MM -MT $< -o $@

  -include $(DEPS)

  $(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
      $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET)
  ```

Comment: Good review.  The only point I think you may wish to add is that `rm -rf` is rather dangerous for `clean`.  Better would be to remove only the generated files.

Comment: @Edward Agreed. It is even better to define `RM = /bin/rm`.

Answer (score 7):

You should pick a single make variable usage style and use it consistently. Personally I use `$(...)` to avoid confusing it with shell variable `${...}` (as I use that much more frequently than command substitution).

You probably want to make `all` as phony also.

Your `run` target will fail if run first thing. Using `run: $(OUTDIR)/terminal` will cause it to bootstrap the binary before using it.

GNU Make has built-in rules for building `.c` files into `.o` files which, if you want, you can use. Which means you just need to add the `.h` files as prerequisites to the `.o` files (if you don't autogenerate them) like this `$(TEMPDIR)/main.o: $(SRC)/terminal.hpp` with no recipe.

As to autogenerating dependencies (which @vnp also mentions) you should read [Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).

These two rules

```
$(OUTDIR): 
    ${MKDIR_P} $(OUTDIR)

$(TEMPDIR):
    ${MKDIR_P} $(TEMPDIR)
```

can be combined into

```
$(OUTDIR) $(TEMPDIR):
        $(MKDIR_P) $@
```

You can avoid needing to manually run the `directories` target by using [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) on the needed directories.

```
$(OUTDIR)/terminal: $(TEMPDIR)/main.o $(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o | $(OUTDIR)
        ....

$(TEMPDIR)/main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp $(SRC)/terminal.hpp | $(TEMPDIR)
        ....

$(TEMPDIR)/terminal.o: $(SRC)/terminal.cpp $(SRC)/terminal.hpp | $(TEMPDIR)
        ....
```

Comment: Well done review, especially the note about the order-only-prerequisites. I had not recalled that feature of gnu make.